# Serial Pins on Cisco MX100

Tags: cisco

does anyone know the Serial Pinout on a Cisco Meraki MX100?

Inside Pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQjGw.jpg

Answer (score 1):

UART Pinout

Look for a 4 pin header named CONN11 in the middle of the PCB. Pin 1 is the marked pin on the PCB closest to the CPU.

```yaml
Pin 1 = VCC Pin 2 = TX Pin 3 = RX Pin 4 = GND
```

> taken form here: https://github.com/riptidewave93/OpenWRT-MX100